# How can I add flags to just search for a certain tag using Exiftool called by a subprocess within Python

Tags: python, subprocess, os.walk, exiftool

I have some code that lists all the files in a directory and then calls a subprocess to use Exiftool to see the metadata for the images. I want to be able to add a flag to see just one specific tag. How can I do this. The flag is -Route. Is it also possible to alert me if a tag isn't a specific value, for example if its meant to be 3 or 4 and it was a 2.

My code is.

```
import os
import subprocess
import sys
filesPath = 'folder to search'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(filesPath):
    for name in files:
        print("echo", os.path.join(root, name))
        subprocess.call(["exiftool", os.path.join(root, name)])
```

Answer (score 0):

I have since solved this issue when it comes to adding the flag. It needs to be done as a separate part of the argument.

```
import os
import subprocess
import sys
filesPath = 'folder to search'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(filesPath):
    for name in files:
        print("echo", os.path.join(root, name))
        subprocess.call(['exiftool', '-Route', os.path.join(root, name)])
```